# React Router переход назад

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1 Есть поиск такого вида `/filter/phone/:number`

2 Есть редактирование `/edit/phone/:number`

При открытии 1 ссылки в `componentWillReciveProps` смотрю все-ли `props` пришли, если да, то запускаю функцию, которая делает фильтр по `number`.

Открываю 1 ссылку выбираю запись и переход на 2 ссылку. Делаю переход назад и открывается старая страница, в адресной строке появляется 1 адрес, но фильтр по `number` нет происходит `componentDidMount`, `componentWillReciveProps` не запускаются при переходе назад.

Правка:
`componentDidMount` работает при переходе назад, но у меня теперь два почти одинаковых кода в `componentDidMount` и `componentWillReciveProps`. Нельзя ли как-нибудь переписать `componentDidMount` чтобы он обработался после получения всех `props` и только потом компонент рендирился?

Comment: Где создаётся компонент?

Comment: @RomanC в смысле где? в главном файле(index.js) наверно, если роутеру нужно открыть компонент по тому какой url стоит в адресной строке

Comment: В принципе я нашел решение, не знаю конечно насколько правильно, но работает

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас код в этих функциях похожий, то выделите этот код в отдельную функцию и вызывайте из обоих мест.

На поведения самих функциях обработчиков не думаю что можно как-то повлиять, но даже если можно я бы этого делать не стал так как это сделает код менее понятным, функции обработчики уже будут работать не как ожидается. Лучше использовать их по прямому назначению.

Я в своём коде так постоянно делаю. У меня данные получаются и в конструкторе и при апдейте. Я этот код выношу в отдельную функцию `GetData()` и вызываю там где это нужно.